# Tipo de datos "image" en SQL Server

Tags: sql, imagen, picturebox

primera consulta que realizo por aquí. Buscando info sobre el tipo de datos **"image"** me salió una página de aqui donde comentan que ese formato va a desaparecer y que lo sugerible ahora es utilizar *varbinary*, eso me genera una confusión ya que a mi proyecto de registro de alumnos he pensado incluirle un campo "picturebox" para añadir la foto del alumno, ojo no soy programador ni mucho menos, el proyecto lo he desarrollado durante meses viendo tutotiales y gracias a Dios me funciona muy bien, puedo registrar alumnos, buscar, actualizar datos, eliminar, todo bien, pero esto que quisiera añadirle me parece muy útil.

Es cierto entonces que ya no se debe utilizar el tipo de datos "image" y debe usarse es varbinary(max)?

Gracias a quien pueda orientarme en esa duda.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En la forma en que está planteada tu pregunta, la respuesta es _si, es cierto, debes utilizar ```varbinary``` para almacenar imágenes directamente en la base de datos_.

Answer (score 1):

En SQL Server, no existe un tipo de datos "image" en las versiones posteriores a la 2005. En su lugar, se recomienda el uso del tipo de datos "varbinary(max)" para almacenar imágenes.

El tipo de datos "varbinary(max)" permite almacenar datos binarios de longitud variable, incluyendo imágenes, y tiene una capacidad máxima de almacenamiento de 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). Para almacenar imágenes de menor tamaño, se pueden utilizar tipos de datos "varbinary" con una longitud máxima especificada.

Para insertar una imagen en una tabla, se utiliza la instrucción INSERT y se proporciona un valor binario para la columna de tipo "varbinary(max)". Para recuperar la imagen almacenada, se utiliza la instrucción SELECT y se convierte el valor binario a un formato de imagen reconocido, como JPEG o PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Es cierto que ya no se debe de utilizar el tipo de datos `image` puesto que puede ser removido en versiones futuras de SQL Server y el tipo de dato `varbinary` ofrece mejor funcionalidad.

Sin embargo, te recomiendo que no almacenes imágenes en tu base de datos. Esto es porque incrementa innecesariamente el almacenamiento de la misma y no está optimizado para ello. En vez de eso, te recomiendo utilizar un gestor de archivos para tus imágenes y solo almacenar la ruta en la base de datos.